# Spring Security Entry Point Integration test differs from manual testing

Tags: spring-security

I have Spring Security configured to redirect back to the home page when an unauthenticated user tries to access a report. When I manually test this, the `@PreAuthorize` expression triggers an `AccessDeniedException` which is caught by Spring's `ExceptionTranslationFilter` which causes a 302 Found redirect to the home page as expected.

In my integration test the exception is caught somewhere in the filter chain ahead of the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and a 403 Forbidden response is returned.

#### Excerpt of applicationContext.xml

```
<!-- Reports configuration -->
<bean id="homeEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/" />
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/reports/**" entry-point-ref="homeEntryPoint">
    <!-- Accessing reports requires having a previous session open so redirect to home -->
    <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/" />
</sec:http>

<!-- Enabled security annotations (i.e. @PreAuthorize) -->
<sec:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

#### Integration Test

```
@Resource
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class SecurityConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Test that the report endpoints will redirect to the home page
     */
    @Test
    public void testReportLoginRedirect() throws Exception {
        String endpoint = "/reports/myReportyWhichRequiresAuth.pdf";

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(get(endpoint))
                .andExpect(status().isFound()) // Error: 403 Forbidden returned
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/"))
                .andReturn();

    }
}
```

Why is the testing setup giving a different result than the manual testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my manual tests automatically set an accepted media type of application/pdf (I assume due to the file extension). In the automated test the default media type accepts all. Because the response value was not PDF an `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` was thrown causing the exception resolver in the `DispatcherServlet:processHandlerException` to return a null ModelAndView and rethrow the original error.

To fix the test I set the accepted media type to application/pdf and corrected the expected redirect URL (unrelated to original error).

```
/**
 * Test that the report endpoints will redirect to the home page
 */
@Test
public void testReportLoginRedirect() throws Exception {
    String endpoint = "/reports/myReportyWhichRequiresAuth.pdf";

    this.mockMvc
            .perform(get(endpoint).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF))
            .andExpect(status().isFound())
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("http://localhost/"))
            .andReturn();

}
```